# Select next <div /> once you know the closest selector with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am developing a website and I can't use jQuery (no discussion about this), so pure javascript and a custom javascript framework is used.

Actually I have found a situation that I don't know how to handle:

I've a group of selectors, that for each one I add a "onclick" event to display / hide a div.

For example:

```
<div id="menu">
    <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="arrow">
            <a class="down">Open / Close</a>
        </div>

        Menu Item

        <div class="extramenu hidden">
            Extra menu items
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="arrow">
            <a class="up">Open / Close</a>
        </div>

        Menu Item 2

        <div class="extramenu">
            Extra menu items
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-item">
        <div class="arrow">
            <a class="down">Open / Close</a>
        </div>

        Menu Item 3

        <div class="extramenu hidden">
            Extra menu items
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I select all "div.menu-item .arrow a" items, so I've 3 items. For each item I add a onclick event (that actually works fine).

What I need to archive is how to select the "closest" class .extramenu inside the div.menu-item. Then detect if the `<a />` have a class .up or .down and if class == .up, add the class hidden; and if class == .down, remove the class hidden.

This a concept of what have to do, it's not javascript code:

```
var elements; // my list of elements

each(elements, function(element) {
    // here element is pointing to the ANCHOR
    add_event(element, "onclick", function(e) {
        var submenu; // here I need to detect the submenu closest to my anchor
        var state; // here I need to know if the anchor has class up or down

        if (state == "up")
        {
            add_class(submenu, "hidden"); // hide the submenu div
            remove_class(element, "up"); // remove the class up
            add_class(element, "down"); // and add the class down
        }
        else if (state == "down")
        {
            remove_class(submenu, "hidden"); // remove the class to show the menu
            remove_class(element, "down"); // remove the class down
            add_class(element, "up"); // and add the class up
        }
    });
});
```

Thank you guys and sorry if it's not well explained, I did my best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`element.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.querySelector) allows you to select elements by CSS selector.

[`element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classList) allows you to access the classes of an element

```
add_event(element, "onclick", function(e) {
    var el = e.target, state;
    var parent = el.parentNode;
    while (!parent.classList.contains('menu-item')) {
        parent = parent.parentNode;
    }
    var submenu = parent.querySelector('extramenu');
        if (el.classList.contains('up')) {
        state = 'up';
    } else {
        state = 'down'
    }

    /* ... */
});
```

You can write the rest of the pseudo code yourself.

I'm assuming your already using Modernizr for supporting legacy browsers like IE8. If your not, then do so.

Comment: Hello @Raynos: first thank you for your reply. I can't not use external libs so... I'm not using Modernizr. In the backend I need to support IE9+, Chrome, FF4+, etc. so no problem at the moment. But with IE9, using: `while (!parent.classList.contains('content-sidebar-box'))` (content-sidebar-box is the correct name) throws me an error: _SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'contains': object is null or undefined_ ... Do you know how to solve it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @udexter classList is not supported in IE9. Use the Shim provided on the MDN page or use `.className.indexOf` instead of `classList.contains`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not exactly the way you want to do this but if class `up` or `down` would be added to parent of the `a` ie `div.arrow` you could do all of the hiding/showing with css combinator `+`. like this:

```
.arrow.down + .extramenu {
  /* the same styles as with hidden class */
}
```

Comment: What is '+' ? Please reference it

Comment: `+` aka [adjacent sibling selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) in this case matches first .extramenu after .arrow.down and doesn't match .extramenu after .arrow without class .down.

Comment: shouldn't it be `.arrow .down + .extramenu` ?

Comment: .extramenu has to be sibling of element with the class .up or .down. That's why change has to be made to add .up/.down class to .arrow not a. `.arrow .down + .extramenu` doesn't reflect markup.

Comment: but the `.down` is the `<a>` inside the `<div>` the `.extramenu` element is a sibling of the `<div>` not the `<a>`

Comment: That's why I proposed to change it, and add .down and .up classes to the div not the link.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you are looking for. Tested in FF5, should be cross-browser.

```
// use in your add_event function  
var submenu = element.parentNode.nextSibling;
while(submenu && (submenu.nodeName!="DIV" || submenu.className.indexOf("extramenu")==-1)) submenu = submenu.nextSibling;
var state = element.className;
```